# Retrieve context value within a Junit Test.

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a Junit test for a tasklet, its something like:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/context/job-runner-context.xml"})
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, StepScopeTestExecutionListener.class })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class InicializaTaskletTest extends BaseTeste {

    @Resource
    private ChunkContext chunkContext;


    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

    }

    @Test
    public void testExecutaTaskletInicializacao() throws Exception {
        AtividadesContext atividadesContext = create();
        ExecutionContext ctx = chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobExecution().getExecutionContext();
        ctx.put(ATIVIDADES_FOLHA, atividadesContext);
        when(service.criarArquivo(diretorio, atividadesContext)).thenReturn(new Emissao();
        RepeatStatus retorno = tasklet.execute(mock(StepContribution.class), chunkContext);
    }

}
```

In the tasklet I want to return a emissao object when I call service.criarArquivo with "diretorio" and "atividadesContext" arguments.

The tasklet is something like:

```
@Value("#{jobExecutionContext['atividadesFolha']}")
private AtividadesContext atividadesContext;

@Override
public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws IOException, AtividadeJaIniciadaException {
    EmissaoArquivoSpai emissao = arquivoSpaiService.criarArquivo(diretorioBaseArquivo, atividadesContext);

    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
}
```

}

The problem is when I execute junit test the inject of atividadesContext doesn't work or It cannot can be put correctly in the context. And the when clause of test returns a null emissao object, because it's not the arguments the method expect. I can use Mockito.any() to do that, but firstly I want to realize why I cannot inject a context object in a junit test.

When I run the job in normal way it works, I can inject atividadesContext normally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Spring Batch unit tests, we use a component called the `JobSynchronizationManager` (there is the equivalent for the Step as well).  Before calling your job scoped bean, you register the `JobExecution` with the `JobSynchronizationManager`.  That makes it available to the `ApplicationContext` for wiring purposes.

So looking at your test, you'd structure it like follows:

```
@Test
public void testExecutaTaskletInicializacao() throws Exception {
    AtividadesContext atividadesContext = create();

    JobExecution jobExecution = new JobExecution(5l);
    ExecutionContext ctx = new ExecutionContext();
    ctx.put(ATIVIDADES_FOLHA, atividadesContext);
    jobExecution.setExecutionContext(ctx);

    JobSynchronizationManager.register(jobExecution);

    when(service.criarArquivo(diretorio, atividadesContext)).thenReturn(new Emissao());
    RepeatStatus retorno = tasklet.execute(mock(StepContribution.class), chunkContext);

    JobSynchronizationManager.release();
}
```

You can read more about the `JobSynchronizationManager` in the documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/scope/context/JobSynchronizationManager.html

Comment: is there another solution? Our project uses SpringBatch 2.1.9. I saw JobSynchronizationManager are in library api since 3.0.

Comment: Use the Step version (`StepSynchronizationManager`) for step scoped beans.